# Disable button once clicked MS bot framework

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am creating chatbot application using MS bot framework. In that, I want to disable both buttons once Yes or No is clicked.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry but the webchat (and other channels) does not support what you want to do, even if it would be useful for many cases.

There is a sort of workaround if you really need to have buttons that cannot be used: use `SuggestedActions` (see doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-send-suggested-actions?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365)), it will look like the following:

[image]

Once clicked the buttons disappear.

Comment: Thanks for the link you given. I did

Answer (score 0):

If you are using facebook messenger you can use quick replies. They will disappear after interactions.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/quick-replies

```cs
Microsoft.Bot.Builder.ConnectorEx.FacebookQuickReply
```

Comment: Thanks, But I am using skype